# WPF Dependency Property Inheritance

Tags: wpf, inheritance, dependency-properties

I have a scenario in which DP Inheritance is not working, my code can also be wrong.

I have a Parent control with a bool Dependency Property "CanShow" on ViewModel. This enables/disables the button on this MainParent Window.

Now, I want a property/DP on child VM, which can set the CanShow property of Parent from childVM to enable/disable the button.

Is this a scenario for Dependency Property Inheritance? - Plz suggest.

I hope so, the scenario is clear.

Thanks,

VJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, inheritance does not work from child to parent, it works from parent to child. You will have to use some sort of event aggregation in order to propagate your event from child to parent which will change CanShow.

Comment: I can understand your point about inheritance. But can you give me some sample code about this scenario thru event aggregation?

Comment: As I have searched about Event Aggregation, this is related to CompositeWPF and it has been discarded from further development.